# Metacharacters in bash commands: Can't find a clear pattern on how it works and how to protect them depending on bash commands

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to find a "clear pattern" of the use of metacharacters in bash commands. Let me be clear!

In the following cases, we have the same results... `[]` is always intepreted as a metacharacter. But why? `" "` or `' '` should protect `[]` from interpretation.

```
grep \[Aa\] filename # it will print all lines with A or a characters
grep [Aa] filename   # the same
grep "[Aa]" filename # the same
grep '[Aa]' filename # the same
```

On the other hand, being "redundant" as it follows, the metacharacters `[]` are protected, i.e., they are not interpreted and are taken as literal characters, fixed strings.

```
grep "\[Aa\]" filename  # it will print all line with [Aa] literal characters
grep '\[Aa\]' filename  # the same
grep -F "[Aa]" filename # the same
```

Why does it happen? `" "`, `\` and `' '` should protect ***any metacharacter*** from interpretation but in grep command it doesn't work! So the "rules" change depending on bash commands? I'm confused about this.

For exemple, using find command to find a file with the name **filename**:

```
find $DIRECTORY_PATH -name filename
```

All metacharacters in **filename** must be protected... it doesn't make any sense: so we need to protect the metacharacters in order to interpret them, to take them as metacharacters and not literal ones?

Comment: Are you confusing the shell giving special meaning to characters and grep also treating the same characters in a special way?

Comment: Is it `filename` or `**filename**`? You can [edit] to clarify / fix the formatting. I just edited the question to add some [inline code formatting](/editing-help#code-spans) -- that might be what you were missing.

Comment: I'm not totally following the question, but I think you're confusing [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntax (regex), which is used by `grep`, and [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), which is used by `find` *as well as* [by Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html). With `"\[Aa\]"`, the quotes tell Bash not to treat the square brackets as a glob and the backslashes tell `grep` not to treat them as regex.

Comment: It's filename, sorry: I fixed it! You shed some light on that, thanks! 

But how do you know that... 

"the `quotes` tell `Bash not to treat the square brackets as a glob` and the `backslashes` tell `grep not to treat them as regex`" in this order

and not: "the `backslashes` tell `Bash not to treat the square brackets as a glob` and the `quotes` tell `grep not to treat them as regex`"? 

In other words, the "first protection", be \ or " ", will protect the metacharacter from the glob interpretation by the Bash or from regex interpretation by the grep?

Comment: I guess technically it goes both ways, but the convention in Bash is to quote instead of using backslashes. I suppose that's cause if you use double-quotes, then you can do variable expansion but not globbing.

Comment: `[` and `]` are not metacharacters in the first place, at least not in shell parlance. A shell metacharacter is one that (when unquoted) can separate words. `[foo]` is a single word (subject to pathname expansion) as far as the shell is concerned. The shell metacharaters are `|`, `&`, `;`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, space, tab, and newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the biggest thing that's confusing you is that the argument goes through two distinct processing steps:

1. bash applies its various parsing rules (applying and removing quotes and escapes, expanding filename wildcards, etc), and then passes the result of that to `grep` as arguments.
2. `grep` interprets whatever it got according to *its* rules, which are very different; escapes have a similar function (but quotes are just ordinary characters), and some of the things you might want to escape are the same, but many aren't.

When you use quotes and/or escapes, some'll get applied (and removed) by bash, and some by `grep` -- but not the *same* ones, and it's important to understand which are applying at which step.

Also, the two steps are done by different programs (bash vs `grep`), and they don't know anything about each other. bash has no idea that the first argument to `grep` will be treated as a regular expression (unless you passed `-F`), and `grep` doesn't know what processing the argument went through before it received it.

To help differentiate what's happening in the two steps, you can create a command that just shows the arguments it got, and use that instead of `grep`. Here's an example using a bash function:

```
$ printargs() {
> if (( $# > 0 ))
> then printf '   «%s»\n' "$@"
> else echo "No arguments"
> fi
> }
$ printargs \[Aa\] filename
   «[Aa]»
   «filename»
$ printargs "[Aa]" filename
   «[Aa]»
   «filename»
$ printargs '[Aa]' filename
   «[Aa]»
   «filename»
```

Note that in each case bash applied *and removed* the quotes/escapes, rather than passing them on to the command. If the command had been `grep` rather than `printargs`, it similarly would've just received `[Aa]` with no quotes or escapes.

So what did they do? Let's try it with no quotes or escapes:

```
$ printargs [Aa] filename
   «[Aa]»
   «filename»
$ touch a A
$ printargs [Aa] filename
   «a»
   «A»
   «filename»
```

Without quotes or escapes, bash treats `[Aa]` as a filename wildcard, and *tries* to expand it to a list of matching filenames. This isn't a filename argument, but bash doesn't know or care about that; it always does this to arguments that contain wildcard characters (including `[...]`) that aren't disabled by quotes or escapes. You didn't have any matching files, so bash just passed it on as it was, but if matching files exist... it'll get replaced. This is why it's a good idea to quote any argument that contains any funny characters that you don't want bash messing with.

Now with "redundant" quoting+escaping:

```
$ printargs "\[Aa\]" filename
   «\[Aa\]»
   «filename»
$ printargs '\[Aa\]' filename
   «\[Aa\]»
   «filename»
```

Here, you can see that bash applied and removed the quotes, but since the escapes were inside (and therefore protected by) them, it didn't apply or remove them. the escapes are passed on to the command, and if the command had been `grep` it would've treated them as disabling the special meaning of `[` and `]` in the regular expression.

BTW, escapes inside double-quotes aren't always passed on to the command; there are some characters that still have special meanings inside double-quotes, and if those are escaped bash will apply *and remove* the escape characters:

```
$ printargs "quote: \", backtick: \`, dollar: \$, etc"
   «quote: ", backtick: `, dollar: $, etc»
```

When passing regular expressions (or anything similarly complex), it's usually best to put single-quotes around them, so bash doesn't mess with the contents (aside from removing the single-quotes). The main exception is if you actually want to pass single-quotes as part of the argument (rather than as protectors around it); that's more complicated.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering! There's only one thing I do not understand: it's when you say " bash applies and removes quotes and escapes... ". Can you please illustrate schematically how this bash process works? What's the point of applying something that will be removed? For example,  bash gets "[Aa]", which it's already quoted: so no need to quote again. Then bash removes quotes: [Aa]. Similarly: [Aa] becomes "[Aa]" (applied) and then [Aa] again (removed). What bash applies or removes it's the first of  the special characters ( \ or " ) it finds in argument: is it right?

Comment: By "apply", I don't mean it's adding quotes or escapes, I mean it's taking their effects into account. So, for example, when you pass `"[Aa]"` as an argument, the way the quotes apply is that they prevent that from being expanded into a list of matching files. So it might be clearer to say that they *have their effect* and then are removed. As for your last sentence: it's more complicated than that, because in some situations you can combine them. For instance, you can use different quoting for different parts of the same argument (`"part1"'part2'`).

Comment: Perfect, @Gordon! I had misunderstood the word "apply", it's clear now! Thanks a lot!